# Where to add IsMonitoringTool meta-data flag in android manifest

Tags: android, manifest

In order to meet google's recent stalkerware policy, developer needs to add isMonitoringTool flag if application collecting certain sensitive user data using app. Can someone help me to define this flag in the manifest.

Here is the document where they have mentioned to do so,
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/12253906#stalkerware_preview

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would love to know the answer to this question too! You'd think if Google wanted us to add the flag like they claim then they would tell us exactly where and how to do it instead of this vague and meaningless "add it to the manifest" nonsense. Can't they provide a code sample or something? Or would that make it too easy for us? Grr.

Comment: @gcdev your answer is correct, it got accepted by google

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a guess, since I cannot find any meaningful documentation at all. And at this point, I don't even know how to test the theory. But I'll offer my guess anyway.

I'm going to guess it goes inside your `application` node. Like this (only your manifest probably has a ton more stuff in it):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest>
    <application>
        <meta-data android:name="IsMonitoringTool" android:value="true" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

My guess is based on the fact that I inherited a manifest with other `meta-data` nodes in that location. Of course, it also has `meta-data` nodes under each `activity` node, but that location doesn't really seem to make sense for this flag.

What's more, the documentation you linked to says that the "app" needs to use the flag, so that matches putting it under the `application` node. So there is my unverifiable guess. I suppose we'll find out if I'm right on November 1, 2022, when this becomes required for relevant apps.
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9934569

Unless someone who works for Google wants to chime in...?

You can see the extensive search results (!) that a Google search gives me:

[image]

Comment: thanks @gcdev, I had submitted a version for review with this declaration in the manifest. Will update you after hearing back from Google.

Comment: @RHL - did you hear back from google?

Comment: A request for better documentation from Google has also been submitted here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/240880966

Comment: @ZayinKrige yes, google accepted. It worked :-)

Comment: I used this answer and submitted to store. No problems so far.

Comment: I have a similar issue, But every time Google Rejected the App Update. We made every possible change mentioned in this thread. Please help us to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Finally it's accepted by Google.

I put `isMonitoringTool` in two places:

1. Before `application` tag
2. Inside `application` tag

It looks not so good but it is accepted. You can try it too.

AndroidManifest code:

```xml
<meta-data android:name="isMonitoringTool"android:value="enterprise_management" />
```

Comment: i have the same issue i'm gonna try your solution

Comment: I have the similar issue, But every time Google Rejected the App Update.

We made every possible change mentioned in this thread. 
Please help us to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The actual correct answer, as per [google documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/12955211?hl=en) is

```
<manifest 
   <application android:isMonitoringTool="child_monitoring">
   …
   </application>
</manifest>
```

The available options are as follows:

`child_monitoring` = App caters to parental control and is specifically targeted at parents who want to keep their kids safe.

`enterprise_management` = App caters to enterprises who want to manage and track devices given to employees.

`other` = App that does not fall in any of the above categories. The Google Play enforcement team will assess whether apps with this value qualify for any valid exemption categories.

Comment: That's what the documentation says. but you get AAPT: error: attribute android:isMonitoringTool not found

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this in side of your manifest tag.

```
    <manifest>
       <meta-data android:name="isMonitoringTool"  android:value="enterprise_management" />
       <application>      
       </application>
    </manifest>
```

you can use base on your category like this child_monitoring, enterprise_management or other